# Converting the HTML description to string to be set as meta description

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, string, meta-tags

I am working on a discussion website.([http://www.wrangle.in/](http://www.wrangle.in)). I added a new feature of HTML formatted description of a topic to it. The HTML formatted description is saved in the database. When the topic is loaded the description is visible in the HTML format. But meta description shows HTML tags even after I used following class to remove HTML tags from string. But this class is not working. I downloaded it from somewhere on the net. It is not removing &nbsp;, &amp; etc. like characters.
Even its not removing all the tags. Please tell how do I make my HTML description to be visible as a textual description in META?

```
/// <summary>
/// Methods to remove HTML from strings.
/// </summary>
public static class HtmlRemoval
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Remove HTML from string with Regex.
    /// </summary>
    public static string StripTagsRegex(string source)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compiled regular expression for performance.
    /// </summary>
    static Regex _htmlRegex = new Regex("<.*?>", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove HTML from string with compiled Regex.
    /// </summary>
    public static string StripTagsRegexCompiled(string source)
    {
        return _htmlRegex.Replace(source, string.Empty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove HTML tags from string using char array.
    /// </summary>
    public static string StripTagsCharArray(string source)
    {
        char[] array = new char[source.Length];
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        bool inside = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            char let = source[i];
            if (let == '<')
            {
                inside = true;
                continue;
            }
            if (let == '>')
            {
                inside = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (!inside)
            {
                array[arrayIndex] = let;
                arrayIndex++;
            }
        }
        return new string(array, 0, arrayIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have just removes HTML tags, it won't convert `&amp;`'s and `&nbsp;`'s.

Using [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) will convert them to readable characters.

Comment: actually its in HttpUtility namespace I think. But still its not working, removing tags but not other &nbsp; like words

Comment: Hmm, decoding the string should have converted the characters, any chance you're building using MVC?